# Is it possible to verify a Google account through my Java GWT application?

Tags: java, gwt, credentials, verify

I want the user to log into my application using the credentials from their Google account, so I want the application to check for the account and if it doesn't exist then return an error or some sort of indication it doesn't exist. If the account does exist I'd like to be able to log in through the application and proceed. Is this possible? I presume it is but I have been unable to to find any information confirming to me that it is.

Answer (score 3):

Use Google like an [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) provider ([which it is](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are running your app on AppEngine, authenticating users through their Google account can be done pretty easily using the UserService class of AppEngine SDK.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers.html